# How can I use required attribute for a group of checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, html, checkboxlist, required

I have a group of checkboxes of which at least one has to be checked to submit the form. For this I named each checkbox identically and set the `required` attribute.

But this doesn't work:

```
<input name="mycheckgroup" type="checkbox" value="1" required />
<input name="mycheckgroup" type="checkbox" value="2" required /> 
<input name="mycheckgroup" type="checkbox" value="3" required />
```

I have to check all three boxes for submitting the form :-(

If this were radio buttons, it worked... But I want at least one or more boxes to be checked.

Can anyone help?

Comment: By default select ONE radio button..it will be easy for you.  [check it here](http://jsfiddle.net/sm48cmze/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I didn't know, that I would need javascript for this solution I didn't tag it, sorry.

But I need it to be checkboxes (no select).

So, here is my working solution using jQuery:

```
<script>
$('.myCB').click(function(){
    if($('#cb1').is(':checked') || $('#cb2').is(':checked') || $('#cb3').is(':checked'))
        $(".myCB").attr("required", false);
    else
        $(".myCB").attr("required", true);
});
</script>

<input name="mycheckgroup" id="cb1" type="checkbox" value="1" class="myCB" required />
<input name="mycheckgroup" id="cb2" type="checkbox" value="2" class="myCB" required /> 
<input name="mycheckgroup" id="cb3" type="checkbox" value="3" class="myCB" required />
```

When checking any checkbox, the required attribute will be removed from all checkboxes in this group.

Answer (score 2):

Without introducing JavaScript the most logical answer to this would be to change your control to a `select` element (which is much more appropriate in your situation):

```html
<select>
  <option value="1" selected>Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

If this isn't a good enough solution for you then you're going to have to handle the validation with JavaScript. I'm not going to provide a solution here as you don't have [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tagged and may already know how to do this yourself anyway.

If you do want to use the JavaScript approach you should edit your question to ask for a possible JavaScript solution and include any libraries you use - although in the spirit of StackOverflow you should attempt to resolve this yourself.

---

> *No, sorry. I, think you misunderstood. I need possibility to check one or more checkboxes. - [cypher75](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356651/how-can-i-use-required-attribute-for-a-group-of-checkboxes/26356828?noredirect=1#comment41372534_26356828)*

In that case you can give your `select` element the `multiple` attribute, allowing you to select more than one option:

```html
<select multiple required>
    <option disabled>Select Multiple</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

I've added an initial `option` element which is `disabled` in order for the `select` element's `required` attribute to take effect.

Comment: No, sorry. I, think you misunderstood. I need possibility to check one ore more checkboxes.

Comment: @cypher75 I've updated my answer. Also I've removed the "Thanks" from your question as this is discouraged on StackOverflow (nothing personal!).

Comment: From a UX perspective, checkboxes are MUCH easier to handle than a multi-select selection box.  I hate having to use two hands to hold CTRL then left click to select multiple items.  However, if you need to do a "one or more checkbox" required condition on checkboxes, you'll need to do more complex JavaScript event triggered validation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the nifty trick that I came up with:

Details: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37825072/1479143

Small snippet:

```
$cbx_group = $("input:checkbox[name='q-8']");
$cbx_group.prop('required', true);
if($cbx_group.is(":checked")){
  $cbx_group.prop('required', false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you enclose the code in form tag and validation will be fired when you perform submit action. And use jQuery to add html5 required attribute dynamically.

**HTML Code**

```
<form>
    <input name="mycheckgroup" type="checkbox" value="1"  />
    <input name="mycheckgroup" type="checkbox" value="2"  /> 
    <input name="mycheckgroup" type="checkbox" value="3"  />
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(e){
    if( $("input[name=mycheckgroup]:checked").length == 0){
        $("input[name=mycheckgroup]:first").attr("required", "required");
    }else{
        $("input[name=mycheckgroup]").removeAttr("required");               
        $("form").submit();
    }           
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2sxy6uqd/2/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is not the solution. In your example you have to check all three boxes to fulfil the requirements. But I want it to require at least one checkbox to be checked ;-)

Comment: By default HTML5 core does not featured group checkboxes. Instead, you can use jquery to validate this. Reference http://jsfiddle.net/2sxy6uqd/1/

Comment: This problem already has been solved using jQuery ;-)

Comment: Okay. But in the other example I found an issue that if you go with 100 check boxes then you need to declare all of them which is a tedious job and if you are using input type submit then it does n't works. More than that other jquery works only if you select / deselect the checkbox.