# HTML 5 make Checkbox required

Tags: html

I have multiple checkbox on my form. I need to make user to select atleast one checkbox or else the form will not submit. I tried required attribute but it checks if user has checked all check boxes.

How to do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218494/using-the-html5-required-attribute-for-a-group-of-checkboxes

Comment: give them the same `class` and write a `for` loop to iterate over them and `if`  at least one is checked raise a flag to `true`

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to add required attributes to all the checkboxes, and when at least one of these checkboxes is checked, remove the required attributes for all the checkboxes using jQuery.

```
var requiredCheckboxes = $(':checkbox[required]');

requiredCheckboxes.change(function(){
    if(requiredCheckboxes.is(':checked')) {
        requiredCheckboxes.removeAttr('required');
    }
    else {
        requiredCheckboxes.attr('required', 'required');
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bruceyang/fe7q8shz/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript that just loops through your html checkboxes and sets the `Variable   issomethingchecked` to TRUE if at least one of them is cheched .

demo http://jsfiddle.net/updpxrfj/2/

```
        var checkboxElements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var issomethingchecked = false;

        for(var i = 0; i < checkboxElements.length; i++) {

        if(checkboxElements[i].type.toLowerCase() == 'checkbox') {

            if (checkboxElements[i].checked == true) {
                issomethingchecked = true;
            }

        }

            if (issomethingchecked === true) {
                // Continue with submiting the form
                  console.log(issomethingchecked);
            }
}
```