# Checkbox required group not working

Tags: jquery, html

So I read the other post about checkbox required attributes but i couldnt get an answer.[Other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218494/using-the-html5-required-attribute-for-a-group-of-checkboxes). It says that i just need to either put the checkbox collection into a DIV or add the "data-grouprequired " attribute to just one checkbox of the group. None of them work.
[The documentation](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/forms.html#Custom-validity) here says that i just need to add it and it is supposed to require at least one checkbox check. Heres my code

```
   <html>
   <body>
   <form>
   <input type="checkbox" name="21" value="ff"      onclick="document.getElementById('21a').removeAttribute('required')" data-grouprequired/> </br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="21" value="zz" onclick="document.getElementById('21a').removeAttribute('required')"/>  </br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="21" value="zzf" onclick="document.getElementById('21a').removeAttribute('required')"/> </br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="21" value="afaf" onclick="document.getElementById('21a').removeAttribute('required')"/> </br> 
   <input type="checkbox" name="21" value="tz" onclick="document.getElementById('21a').removeAttribute('required')"></br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="21" value="gaga" onclick="document.getElementById('21a').setAttribute('required', true)" /></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="21" value="a" onclick="document.getElementById('21a').removeAttribute('required')"/></br>
   <b> Text       </b><input type="text" name="quarter" required ></br>
   <input type="submit">

  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

With this i am not getting the functionality I need. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: check this answer from the other post your are doing in the wrong way http://stackoverflow.com/a/30055382/2488916

Comment: I think the one above that is closer to what i need. With the one you are suggesting I can implement it to work only at button click. With the other one i think it will make it work as the required attribute of a radio group. And also isnt the documentation I link not true ?