# angular2 group of checkboxes with required attribute

Tags: checkbox, angular, angular2-forms

i want to create a template-driven form in Angular2 (*RC5*), that will include a group of check-boxes, bounded to specific attributes of an object. Right now, i have such group, bounded to the corresponding array like:

```
<div class="checkbox" *ngFor="let prop of properties">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option" id="option [(ngModel)]="prop.state"/> 
    {{prop.name}}
  </label>
</div>
```

Although this is pretty straightforward, i cannot figure out how to add a **required** attribute to this group of check-boxes. What i mean by that, is that i need to force user to select **AT LEAST** one of the group check-boxes, otherwise form validation will fail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a bot? I am talking about Angular 2...

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218494/using-the-html5-required-attribute-for-a-group-of-checkboxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have an object or array with all of your states, if I'm reading correctly, i.e.

```js
properties = [
  { state: false },
  { state: false },
  { state: false },
  // ... etc
];
```

You could figure out if at least one is checked by listening to `(ngModelChange)` on each of the elements. When it fires, you can then check to make sure at least one of prop's states is true, i.e. in your template file:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option" id="option" [(ngModel)]="prop.state" (ngModelChange)="onCheckboxChange()"/>
```

And in your class, have a field like `atLeastOnePropIsTrue`, and then your `onCheckboxChange` function can look like this:

```js
function onCheckboxChange() {
    this.atLeastOnePropIsTrue = this.properties.find(a => a.state === true) != null;
}
```

It's not exactly pretty, but it would work.