# FormBuilder multiple checkboxes required using EntityType Field

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.3

How can I get required multiple checkboxes with the EntityType Field instead of a ChoiceType Field in Symfony3? Actually, I'm using:

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

->add('typesAdresses' , EntityType::class , array(
    'class' => 'EKUserBundle:TypeAdresse',
    'required' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => true,
));
```

This will output multiple checkboxes but not as required.

In my form it must be required.

Answer (score 3):

Checkboxes behaviour is different and you might get around it using the [choice_attr](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-attr) option:

```
$builder
    ->add('typesAdresses' , EntityType::class , array(
        'class' => TypeAddresse::class,
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
        'choice_attr' => function($val, $key, $index) {
            return array('required' => true);
        },
    ))
;
```

**However**: I assume what you wish to achieve is “at least 1 checkbox checked in a group of checkboxes”. This is a rather different issue on its own and is more thoroughly explained in [Using the HTML5 “required” attribute for a group of checkboxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218494/using-the-html5-required-attribute-for-a-group-of-checkboxes)
 So you'll probably have to approach this with some JavaScript and leave out the required attributes in your FormType.

Comment: thank for replying me . like you said I want that at least 1 checkbox checked . I tried to fix it without javascript .