# A group of checkboxes should be required, not each individual checkbox

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I have a form for a user create custom questions. The user needs to introduce the question and also the type of field (text, long text, checkbox, select menu, radio button) to create a custom question.

Then I have the Question model that has the getHtmlInput() function to output in the view the different types based on the custom question type.

And its working fine, but there is one issue: When the custom question type is a checkbox and the question is required that should mean that the user needs to answer that question but should not mean that the user needs to select all checkboxes. But with the code below when a checkbox field is required all checkboxes related to that field all need to be checked. Do you know how to solve that issue?

And also do you know how to, if the custom question is required add inside each question label this "`<span class="text-primary">*</span>`"?

Question model:

```
class Question extends Model
{

    public static $typeHasOptions = [
        'radio_btn',
        'select_menu',
        'checkbox'
    ];


    public function hasOptions() {
        return in_array($this->type, self::$typeHasOptions);
    }

    public function getHtmlInput($name = "", $options = "", $required = false, $class = "", $customtype = false) {
        $html = '';
        $html .= $customtype == 'select_menu' ? "<select name='participant_question' class='form-control' " . ($required ? " required" : "")
            . ">" : '';

        if (empty($options)) {
            switch ($customtype) {
                case "text":
                    $html .= " 
                    <input type='text' name='participant_question' class='form-control'" . ($required ? " required" : "")
                        . ">";
                    break;

                case "file":
                    $html .= " 
                    <input type='file' name='participant_question' class='form-control'" . ($required ? " required" : "") . ">";
                    break;

                case "long_text":
                    $html .= "

                <textarea name='participant_question' class='form-control' rows='3'" . ($required ? " required" : "") . ">"
                        . $name .
                        "</textarea>";
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($options as $option) {
                switch ($customtype) {
                    case "checkbox":
                        $html .= " 
                <div class='form-check'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='participant_question[]' value='" . $option->value . "' class='form-check-input'" . ($required ? " required" : "") . ">" .
                            '    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">' . $option->value . '</label>' .
                            "</div>";
                        break;
                    case "radio_btn":
                        $html .= " 
                <div class='form-check'>
                    <input type='radio' name='participant_question[]' value='" . $option->value . "' class='form-check-input'" . ($required ? " required" : "") . ">" .
                            '    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">' . $option->value . '</label>' .
                            "</div>";
                        break;
                    case "select_menu":
                        $html .= "<option value='" . $option->value . "'>" . $option->value . "</option>";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        $html .= $customtype == 'select_menu' ? "</select>" : '';

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Use of the getHtmlInput() in the view:

```
@if ($allParticipants == 0)
    @foreach($selectedRtype['questions'] as $customQuestion)
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
            @if($customQuestion->hasOptions() && in_array($customQuestion->type, ['checkbox', 'radio_btn', 'select_menu']))
                {!! $customQuestion->getHtmlInput(
                    $customQuestion->name,
                    $customQuestion->options,
                    ($customQuestion->pivot->required == '1'),
                    'form-control',
                    $customQuestion->type)
                !!}

            @else
                {!! $customQuestion->getHtmlInput(
                    $customQuestion->name,
                    [],
                    ($customQuestion->pivot->required == '1'),
                    'form-control',
                    $customQuestion->type)
                !!}
            @endif
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="participant_question_required[]"
                   value="{{ $customQuestion->pivot->required }}">
            <input type="hidden"
                   value="{{ $customQuestion->id }}"
                   name="participant_question_id[]"/>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Generated HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="">


  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">Text</label>
    <input type="text" name="participant_question" class="form-control" required="">
    <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="participant_question_id[]">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">Checkbox</label>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="participant_question[]" value="check1" class="form-check-input" required="">  
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">check1</label>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="participant_question[]" value="check2" class="form-check-input" required="">    
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">check2</label>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="participant_question_id[]">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">Radio</label>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" name="participant_question[]" value="rad1" class="form-check-input">  
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">rad1</label>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" name="participant_question[]" value="rad2" class="form-check-input">   
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">rad2</label>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" value="3" name="participant_question_id[]">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">select</label>
    <select name="participant_question" class="form-control">
      <option value="select1">select1</option>
      <option value="select2">select2</option>
    </select>

    <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" value="4" name="participant_question_id[]">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">textarea</label>
    <textarea name="participant_question" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" value="5" name="participant_question_id[]">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">file</label>
    <input type="file" name="participant_question" class="form-control" required="">
    <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" value="6" name="participant_question_id[]">
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Store">
</form>
```

Comment: "[...] checkbox and the question is required is necessary to mark **all** checkboxes, but the user should be able to mark **only one** checkbox." Which one is it? That statement is rather conflicting... Also, if you want to enforce only a single checked option, why not use a `radio` input?

Comment: You probably can force them to only select one, perhaps with JS whereby when one is ticked the others are disabled, and unticking re-enables them all. But, radio inputs already exist for this exact requirement

Comment: Thanks, because its a custom question, the user can create a question of any type (text, checkbox, etc) and then the question should appear in the veiw with the correct type. If the user create a custom question of type checkbox and defined the custom question as a required question then in the view the user needs to answer  that custom question. But if the question is of type checkbox and the question is required that should mean that the user needs to answer that question but  should not mean that the user needs to select all checkboxes.

Comment: I updated the question to try to explain better.

Comment: This will help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218494/using-the-html5-required-attribute-for-a-group-of-checkboxes

Comment: Thanks, but in this case the checkbox is generated using the getHtmlInput() with "  case "checkbox": $html .= " <div class='form-check'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='participant_question[]' value='" . $option->value . "' class='form-check-input'" . ($required ?: " required") . ">" .
                            '    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">' . $option->value . '</label>' .
                            "</div>";
                        break;". And can exist multiple checkboxes required questions.